# angularjs routing wrong link

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-routing

I'm using cordova angularjs together. I will use the routeprovider. 
index.js:

```
var appGenerator = angular.module('appGenerator', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

appGenerator.config(function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
});

        appGenerator.config(['$routeProvider' function ($routeProvider) {

         $routeProvider
             .when('/', {
                templateUrl: "partials/tablePage.html",
                 controller: "MainCtrl"
             })
             .when('/contacts', {
                 templateUrl: "partials/contacts.html",
                 controller: "ContactsCtrl"
            }).otherwise({
                 redirectTo: '/'
             }); }]);
```

html:

```
<a href="#/{{table.tablename}}" onclick="callTable()">{{table.tablename}}</a>
```

But I get an `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///contacts)` error

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: use `ngHref` instead `href` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: Also tried. But same problem.

Comment: I had the same problem but solved it calling `$location.path('/contacts');` in a `ng-click` handler on the `<a>` element.